# Finding all rectangles with fault-free tilings of the P-pentomino

Tags: tiling, polyomino

I am trying to find all rectangles with fault-free tilings of the P pentomino. (A fault is a vertical or horizontal line inside the rectangle that is not crossed by any tiles; a fault-free tiling is thus a tiling without such lines.)

My basic strategy is to find "basic" fault free tilings, and then extend them.

So far, the following extensions are possible:

- $5 \times 2n$ rectangles can be extended to $5 \times (2n + 6k)$ for $n \geq 1$.
- $m \times 2n$ rectangles can be extended to $(m + 5) \times 2n$ for $m \geq 5$ and $n \geq 2$.
- $(5m + 5) \times (2n + 5)$ rectangles can be extended to $(5m + 15) \times (2n + 5)$ for $m, n \geq 1$.

And I have the following basic rectangles:

- $2 \times 5$, $4 \times 5$, $6 \times 5$
- $7 \times 10$, $9 \times 10$, $11 \times 10$
- $7 \times 15$, $9 \times 15$, $11 \times 15$, $13 \times 15$, $15 \times 15$

The idea is to find if all possible rectangles can have fault free tilings, so I use [this table](http://polyominoes.org/data/5P) for comparison.

My question is, is there some systematic way to deal with this "system of rectangles"? How do I know I have everyone? Or if I can make either list of basic rectangles or the list of extensions shorter?

(The P-pentomino is probably manageable with a bit of care, but I make many mistakes which made me wonder if there is a more systematic way. Also, I plan to examine the Y-pentomino next, and since it has 40 prime rectangles, I expect it to have at least as many basic rectangles.)

This picture summarizes the above. Tilings that only have yellow tiles are "basic"; colored tiles are "[cylinders](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2483637/is-there-a-word-for-a-polyomino-with-n-connected-cells-in-each-row/2546994#2546994)" inserted into basic tilings to extend them.
[image]